# Jcarousel Active class

Tags: jquery

There are other posts on this, but mine is set up slightly differently and I can't quite figure out the last step.

This is my Jquery for the Jcarousel slider:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).attr("id")));
    return false;
});

jQuery('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.next();
    carousel.options.scroll = jQuery.jcarousel.intval(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    return false;
});

jQuery('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.prev();
    carousel.options.scroll = jQuery.jcarousel.intval(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    return false;
});

jQuery('#offerings li a').bind('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(index[1]));
    //carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
    $("#offerings li a").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
});
};
```

This works great for adding an active class when you click on a link in the external control (#offerings), but when you use the prev and next buttons, it does not update the menu active class.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
carousel.options.scroll = jQuery.jcarousel.intval(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
```

Comment: The commented out line shouldn't be commented out? or it's the line that causes a problem and thus is commented out? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have two functions to scroll.
For example:

```
.next()
```

and then you followed it by another scroll function

```
.scroll
```

Solution:
use in `next()` function only next and same to previous function.